# Unit testing - when/how to stub?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am trying to get better at unit testing my code - including trying out some tdd. One question I have is how I should go about testing an object that parses a csv file. Let me give a small example...

```
class EventLog {
    parse() {
        // load csv file, create array of Events
    }

    getEvents(options) {
        // depending on options, return correct set of events
    }
}

class Event {}
```

So first, I want to write tests for my `getEvents` method that makes sure that the different options produce the correct results. In this case would I want to create a stub for parse that I can pass a set of `Events`, and then run my tests against that dataset?

Second, I will need to test the parse method. Plan to test simple things like when the file doesn't exist, format doesn't match expected, correct `Events` are created etc. For this should I just store some sample `.csv` files that cover the cases I need? Or would pulling a `loadCsv()` method out and stubbing that be more effective?

Answer (score 1):

How difficult is the class to use?

If it's easy, like a parser that takes some string, then you may consider just using it directly. With ES6 classes, you may even be able to declare a new `class TestEventLog extends EventLog` and use inheritance as a minimal stub. That has the least overhead and is my favorite strategy.

If the class is especially complex, remember that with small (unit) tests you want to focus on a small portion of code. If you see a large number of methods being called from a class that you aren't testing, that is a smell of poorly stubbed tests.

In this case, I would probably start by inheriting and replacing:

```
class TestEventLog extends EventLog {
  parse() {
    // ignore arguments, return known test data
    return [['foo', 1], ['bar', 2]];
  }
}
```

The guiding principle should be to introduce as little code as possible. The more code you write to support tests, the more code you need to test.

Comment: What would the advantages/disadvantages of using inheritance like that vs using a sinon stub method?

Comment: @TroyCosentino typically very little, I just prefer inheritance for the simplicity of it. You can't get much more to-the-point than `extends`. When a class needs more complex mocking or I don't want any of the original behavior, then stubs come in handy.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the info! Definitely helps with getting my head into the right mentality